# How can I print an array in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

For example, I have an array of type int and size 3, it has elements 1, 2, 3  When I try to print it in `JOptionPane` with loops, it makes three different panes.

When I try:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, array );
```

It gives garbage values.

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution.  How do I display the array in an option pane?

Comment: That's not the garbage value . You get that value because java `Object` class has `toString` method like this :    `public String toString() {
 return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arrays.toString ()` as :

```
    int [] arr = new int [3];
    arr[0]=1;
    arr[1]=2;
    arr[2]=3;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Wrap the list in a JScrollPane if 'size matters'.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JList(array));
```

E.G.

[image: Using a JList]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ArrayDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] array = {
                "JList",
                "JTable for 2D array",
                "HTML in JLabel",
                "Delimited String in JLabel"
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JList(array));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(In regard to array `toString()`)

> It gives garbage values.

Obscure, yes - garbage, no.  AFAIU it is the reference to the array in memory.

> ..I have an array of type int

Note that a `JList` array constructor requires objects, so it would need `Integer` rather than `int`.  To convert from `int[]` to `Integer[]` do this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ArrayDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayPrimitive = {1,2,3};
        final Integer[] array = new Integer[arrayPrimitive.length];
        for (int ii=0; ii<arrayPrimitive.length; ii++) {
            array[ii] = arrayPrimitive[ii];
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, new JList(array) );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, Arrays.toString(array));
```

The default `toString()` method for arrays in Java prints, as you called it, *garbage values*.

## See also

- [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/605744)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(array.length);
for (int i=0;i<array.length;builder.append(array[i++])) builder.append("\n");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, builder.toString(), "Printing results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Reason for using `StringBuilder` is that it won't make different panes for you. If you simply go for printing one `String` at a time, you are bound to get different panes.

Comment: and if I want to print two arrays in columns?

Comment: See the example on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399281/how-to-print-multiple-arrays-of-different-types-in-java) page to get an idea about printing multiple arrays.

Comment: You will have to run different `for` loops for each array,appending into the `StringBuilder` for each array one at a time and then printing them.